# Javascript: How to execute synchronous operations in parallel

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Following is a non-recursive js code I wrote to walk json objects and perform an action over it.

```
//function to disallow property for any node if required
function disallowAdditionalProperties(node) {
    //console.log('working on '+JSON.stringify(node))
    if (typeof node === 'object') {
        if (node.properties) {
            //console.log('has properties')
            node.additionalProperties = false
        }
    }
}

//function to walk trhough all json nodes and perform any action on it
function jsonWalkAction (json,action) {
    //console.log('prior schema');
    //console.log(json)
    var node = json;
    var rootName = 'root';
    var hrchy = {'root':{}};
    var nodeKeys = Object.keys(node);
    var attrib;
    var  i = 0;
    if (nodeKeys.length>0) {
        action(node)
        do {
            attrib = nodeKeys[i++];
            //console.log("attrib: "+attrib);
            if (attrib && typeof node[attrib] === "object") {

                //capture current node info
                hrchy[rootName].pos = i;
                hrchy[rootName].ref = node;
                //initiate next node traversal
                i = 0;
                hrchy[attrib] = {};
                hrchy[attrib].parent = rootName;
                node = node[attrib];

                //perform action on this node
                action(node);

                //update 
                hrchy[attrib].ref = node;
                nodeKeys = Object.keys(node);
                rootName = attrib;
            }
            //check if no more attributes remain for this node
            while (i>=Object.keys(node).length) {
                //break if already on root node
                if (rootName === 'root') break;
                //switch to parent
                prevName = rootName;
                rootName = hrchy[rootName].parent;
                hrchy[rootName].ref[prevName]=node;
                node = hrchy[rootName].ref;
                nodeKeys = Object.keys(node);
                i = hrchy[rootName].pos;
            }


        } while (Object.keys(node).length > i);
    }
}
```

Now what if I have to execute a synchronous action on each of selected instead of just adding a false additional properties flag - how can I put execution of each synchronous call in parallel i.e. each node action in a separate thread in javascript. An example could be that each node is loaded with data and the code does intensive parsing on it.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Comment: My best advice is work with promises and async/await. Learning about that will pay off!

Comment: Hi @Bergi - Thanks this suits well - are you aware if there is a min file for cluster.

Comment: @Bergi: No problem - found node-minify